# How to always show poll results view instead of vote view on poll single node?

Tags: 7, polls

The default poll runtime settings don't fit our needs. We need to have a time window with a specific start date and a specific end date. When it's too early the button and radio inputs will be hidden. I solved that by a simple `hook_form_alter()`. But when it's too late the results view should be displayed and I can't find out how.

All anonymous users.

I know I could `hook_init()` everybody to the `node/%nid/results` URL. Problem is, this URL gets unavailable when the user already voted. How does Drupal know if someone already voted? How can I call the clean URL alias of a node and ensure that always the results view will be displayed even when the poll settings still say the poll is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `template_preprocess_node()` to hook in :D

```
function MYTEMPLATE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  // check if we are in the right place
  if ($vars['type'] == 'poll') {
    if ( /* add other conditions here if you need to */ ) {
      // then unset the voting view first
      unset($vars['content']['poll_view_voting']);
      // and add the results view instead
      $node = node_load($vars['nid']);
      $vars['content']['poll_view_results'] = array('#markup' => poll_view_results($node, TRUE, FALSE));
    }
  }
}
```